# python simple qu

Tags: key

The question has racked my brains

There are 26 underscores presenting English alphabet in-sequence.
means that letter a,b and g should be substituted by the letter k, j and r respectively, while all the other letters are not substituted.

how do I do like this? How can python detect each underscore = each English alphabet?

I thought I could use `str.replace to do this` but it's more difficult than I thought.

thanks

Comment: sounds like you need a mapping? why not use `dict`?

Comment: Well, that is a great suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `str.translate`:

```
In [8]: from string import ascii_lowercase

In [9]: text.translate({ord(l): l if g == '_' else g for g, l in zip(guess, ascii_lowercase)})
Out[9]: 'i km jen .'
```

This maps elements of `string.ascii_lowercase` to elements of `guess` (by position). If an element of `guess` is the underscore, the corresponding letter from `ascii_lowercase` is used instead.

Comment: great ... How should I do 
if text is Ab-Bcdeef, and the guess is _j__r_____________________, the returned text should be: Aj-jCDrrf ? 
That means all other letters which are not substituted would be capital letters, while some certain letters which are substituted would be small letters.

Answer (score 0):

If you had a list of the alphabet, then the list of underscores, enter a for loop and then just compare the two values, appending to a list if it does or doesn’t

Comment: Use `import string; string.ascii_lowercase` for a list of the alphabet.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> text = "i am ben ."
>>> guess = "kj____r___________________"
>>> d = dict()
>>> for i in xrange(len(guess)):
...     if(guess[i] != "_"):
...             d[chr(i+97)] = guess[i]
... 
>>> d
{'a': 'k', 'b': 'j', 'g': 'r'}
>>> text_list = list(text)
>>> text_list 
['i', ' ', 'a', 'm', ' ', 'b', 'e', 'n', ' ', '.']
>>> for i in xrange(len(text_list)):
...     if(text_list[i] in d):
...             text_list[i] = d.get(text_list[i])
... 
>>> text_list
['i', ' ', 'k', 'm', ' ', 'j', 'e', 'n', ' ', '.']
>>> text_final = "".join(text_list)
>>> text_final 
'i km jen .'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Zip them:

```
import string
zipped = zip(string.ascii_lowercase, "kj____r___________________")
print(zipped)
# [('a', 'k'), ('b', 'j'), ('c', '_'), ('d', '_'), ('e', '_'), ('f', '_'), ('g', 'r'), ('h', '_'), ('i', '_'), ('j', '_'), ('k', '_'), ('l', '_'), ('m', '_'), ('n', '_'), ('o', '_'), ('p', '_'), ('q', '_'), ('r', '_'), ('s', '_'), ('t', '_'), ('u', '_'), ('v', '_'), ('w', '_'), ('x', '_'), ('y', '_'), ('z', '_')]
```

Convert it into a dict:

```
dict_ = dict(zipped)
print(dict_)
# {'a': 'k', 'b': 'j', 'c': '_', 'd': '_', 'e': '_', 'f': '_', 'g': 'r', 'h': '_', 'i': '_', 'j': '_', 'k': '_', 'l': '_', 'm': '_', 'n': '_', 'o': '_', 'p': '_', 'q': '_', 'r': '_', 's': '_', 't': '_', 'u': '_', 'v': '_', 'w': '_', 'x': '_', 'y': '_', 'z': '_'}
```

And then use a for loop for the substitution:

```
inp = "I am Ben."
result = ""
for letter in inp:
  if letter in dict_:
    if dict_[letter] != "_"
      result += dict_[letter]
      continue
  result += letter
```

It all combined:

```
def sub(text, criteria):
  import string
  dict_ = dict(zip(string.ascii_lowercase, criteria))
  result = ""
  for letter in text:
    if letter in dict_:
      if dict_[letter] != "_":
        result += dict_[letter]
        continue
    result += letter
  return result

 >>> sub("I am Ben. abg abg", "kj____r___________________")
 'I km Ben. kjr kjr'
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer ><... Love you.

Comment: How should I do 
if text is "KKb-Bcdeef", and the guess is _j__r_____________________, the returned text should be: "KKj-jCDrrf" ? 
That means all other letters which are not substituted would be capital letters, while some certain letters which are substituted would be small letters.

Answer (score 0):

Let's solve your issue step by step without making it too much complicated:

> First step :

So first step is data gathering which user providing or you already have :

Suppose you have one list of a-z alphabets and other list have replaced "_" underscore and letters :

if you don't have let's gather data :

a-z alphabet list :

```
alphabet_list=list(map(chr,range(97,123)))
```

it will give :

```
>>> print(alphabet_list)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

next if you don't have underscore list :

```
underscore_list=[]
for i in range(1,27):
    b.append("_")
```

and let's modify this list a little so make it like yours :

```
modified_underscore_list=['k', 'j', '_', '_', '_', '_', 'g', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
```

> Second step:

Now you have all things which needed to solve problem let's work on the second step now :

we have to map each element of first list to other list so we can save this result to dictionary format:

(Remember one thing dict keys can't be same or duplicate but values can be)

So let's iterate over list one and list two and then save the output to dictionary format :

For this purpose we need to iterate on both list so we will use built-in zip function :

```
final_output={}   #we will save our iteration output in this dict
for i,j in zip(alphabet_list,modified_underscore_list):
    final_output[i]=j
```

we can see the dict now :

```
{'p': '_', 'k': '_', 'w': '_', 't': '_', 'i': '_', 'c': '_', 'b': 'j', 'j': '_', 'a': 'k', 's': '_', 'g': 'g', 'x': '_', 'm': '_', 'l': '_', 'h': '_', 'o': '_', 'd': '_', 'n': '_', 'y': '_', 'r': '_', 'e': '_', 'u': '_', 'f': '_', 'v': '_', 'q': '_', 'z': '_'}
```

Now we have mapped data :

move to third and last step :

> Third Step :

Now ask for input from user and check if character's of user's string in our final dictionary, if yes then replace only "a" "g" and "b" with value of those keys from our dictionary , simple:

```
ask_input=str(input("enter string"))

ask=list(ask_input)

for i,j in enumerate(ask):
    if j in final_output:
        if j=="a" or j=="b" or j=="g":
            ask[i]=final_output.get(j)
print("".join(ask))
```

So our full code would be :

```
alphabet_list=list(map(chr,range(97,123)))

modified_underscore_list=['k', 'j', '_', '_', '_', '_', 'g', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']



final_output={}


for i,j in zip(alphabet_list,modified_underscore_list):
    final_output[i]=j



ask_input=str(input("enter string"))

ask=list(ask_input)

for i,j in enumerate(ask):
    if j in final_output:
        if j=="a" or j=="b" or j=="g":
            ask[i]=final_output.get(j)
print("".join(ask))
```